# Reading Serial Data Stream from Bluetooth 5 LE DevBoard via Rumble

Tags: rust, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to read a serial data stream coming from a bluetooth low energy devboard. The firmware registers as UART emulation service ( custom UUID ), and sends data via Receive_Characteristic ( custom UUID ). The serial data being send is just an incrementing numbers.

Using [rumble](https://github.com/mwylde/rumble/), I am able to form a connection to the device, and read something, but not the stream. What follows is a minimal working code example:

```
    let manager = Manager::new().unwrap();

    let mut adapter = manager
        .adapters()
        .expect("could not list adapters")
        .into_iter()
        .find(|a| a.name == self.adapter_name)
        .expect("could not find adapter by name");

    println!("power cycle adapter");
    adapter = manager.down(&adapter).unwrap();
    adapter = manager.up(&adapter).unwrap();
    println!("connect adapter");

    let central = adapter.connect().unwrap();
    central.start_scan().unwrap();
    println!(
        "find desired {:?} peripheral...",
        &self.device_name
    );

    // keep scanning for 10 s
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    central.stop_scan().unwrap();

    let peripherals = central.peripherals();



    let mdevice = central
        .peripherals()
        .into_iter()
        .find(|perf| {
            perf.properties()
                .local_name
                .iter()
                .any(|name| name.contains(&self.device_name))
        })
        .expect("could not find peripheral by name");

    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

    match mdevice.connect() {
        Ok(d) => {
            println!("mdevice connected");
            d
        }
        Err(err) => {
            eprintln!("error connecting to mdevice: {:?}", err);
            panic!()
        }
    };
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("discovering characteristics");

    for ch in mdevice.discover_characteristics().unwrap().into_iter() {
        println!("found characteristic: {:?}", ch);
    }
    std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));
    println!("get desired characteristic");
    let receive_characteristic = mdevice
        .discover_characteristics()
        .unwrap()
        .into_iter()
        .find(|c| {
            RECEIVE_CHARACTERISTIC == c.uuid
        })
        .expect("could not find given characteristic");


    // this is some testing code to print out received data
    let (tx, rx) = std::sync::mpsc::channel();

    std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let data = match mdevice.read(&receive_characteristic) {
            Ok(d) => d,
            Err(err) => { println!("received an error {:?}", err); 
                          Vec::new()}
        };
        println!("send : {:02?}", data);
        match tx.send(data) {
            Ok(d) => d,
            Err(e) => println!("error {:?}", e)
        };
    });    

    loop {
        let dd = rx.recv();
        println!("received : {:02?}", dd.unwrap());
    }

    Ok(())
```

Using rumble, I am able to connect to the device, but getting a stream is weird. I keep getting the same number in a vec, but get sometimes a number being in range of the increment. Is reading the serial stream being done correctly?

*EDIT*: I am currently using the nRF52840-DK development board. The firmware sends out incrementing numbers from 0 to 255, and then repeats the sequence.

Comment: Can you please add more details to your question? if you can share exactly what dev board, what stream of numbers you would expect and what you are actually getting it would be easier to see what might be wrong.

Comment: yes, sure. I just did.

Comment: OK, what hardware are you using on your computer's side? Have you tried to set up a virtual serial port on Linux to see if you receive the sequence you expect? Maybe something like [this](http://www.userk.co.uk/arduino-bluetooth-linux/)

Comment: I am currently using the on-board hci device

hci0: Type: Primary  Bus: USB
 BD Address: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 96:6
 HCI Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Revision: 0x100
 LMP Version: 4.2 (0x8)  Subversion: 0x100
 Manufacturer: Intel Corp. (2)

Thank you for the example. This implies the support of rfcomm, which is not part of bluetooth LE, but i am surely wrong here. Nevertheless I tried to bind the device to a virtual port (if rfcomm is what you mean by that), and the channel closes immediately.

Comment: What I mean is you should find  way to verify that your dev board is working and sending data correctly. RFCOMM should work with LE, you can use `hcitool lescan ` .  Are you able to bind? There are some useful [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/248817/how-to-i-connect-a-raw-serial-terminal-to-a-bluetooth-connection) on askubuntu, maybe you can take a look and see if they help?

Comment: Thank you for the hints. The device can be found via lescan, but not be bound. I tried to bind to a an rfcomm channel, but without success. The firmware has been tested, but on a different OS (osx, while currently working on linux). This might be a hint, on whats missing.

Comment: I think you're on the right track there, maybe try with other LE devices to see if you have a driver problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

The main problem was, that I didn't fully understand the GATT profile and thus the Bluetooth LE protocol. This [resource](https://learn.adafruit.com/introduction-to-bluetooth-low-energy/gatt) gives a good introduction into this topic.

The solution is to subscribe to data (event) updates, after the device has been connected and register an event handler, that reacts to incoming data. It was that simple.

```
// ... same code as before, but only the relevant pieces are shown.
mdevice.connect().expect("Could not connect to device");
std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

let chars = mdevice.discover_characteristics()
.expect("Discovering characteristics failed");

std::thread::sleep(std::time::Duration::from_secs(1));

let receive_characteristic = chars.clone().into_iter()
.find(|c| 
{
                // The constant is just a fixed array
                RECEIVE_CHARACTERISTIC == c.uuid
}).expect("Could not find given characteristic");

// subscribe to the event
mdevice.subscribe(&receive_characteristic)

mdevice.on_notification(Box::from(move |v : rumble::api::ValueNotification| 
{
// do something with the received data
}));
```